# Send command to a process

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have this program that several users on the same computer is using (windows 2008 server environment with remote desktop clients).

When the program is ended normally, it deletes a special file in its working directory.
I need to be able to send all instances of this program a command to cleanly shut down (so that it deletes the file at exit).

What would be the best way to do this, and how?
I assume getting the pids for each instance is a start, but then what?
Anyone have any good ideas?

Edit: Forgot to mention, it's a WinForm (not a command line) program.

Edit2: My comment was too long, so I guess it's best to just edit the question instead...

The file it's deleting is actually a file containing it's pid.
The reason for having this file is to make sure that the user doesn't attempt to start the program twice with the same arguments (login information).

The main program (control center) that is actually starting the client program is keeping track of the pidfile in the users directory.
If it discovers the file it reads the pid and tries to see if the pid exists.
If not, it actually does delete the file and is letting the user start the client window.

I guess by using that procedure, I simply could make it look for all pids asociated with my application and simply kill them, ut I'd prefere to be able to send a shutdown command, as that would also notify the user in an IM that the program is shutting down for whatever the reason given. (Client initiated, remote server initiated, or, as in this case "Local server initiated").

Comment: you cannot cleanly shut down and application based on pid.

Comment: Any "delete file at exit" requirement is a headache that's going to cause trouble.  Power loss is a classic failure mode.  A program can just as easily delete that file when it starts back up.

Comment: I agree with Hans, have you considered deleting the file at startup or storing the value in memory, e.g. as a `string`.

Comment: @HansPassant Commented your comment in the original question.

Comment: Right, that's *exactly* the headache I was talking about.  Power goes out, comes back on, some poor soul needs to go from machine to machine to delete that file by hand so the program can run again.  Single-instance apps are not done that way, just google "single-instance app" and take the first hit.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Having worked in Linux, and not used to operate with pids in windows, I just hoped/asumed there was a way to cleanly shut down a program by it's pid, like "kill -3 pid"

Comment: @HansPassant Not sure if you misunderstood me. There would be no need to manually delete them. In your example with a power cut.. the coputer dies and comes back up again, the file is there. The control center sees the file and reads the pid written inside it. Looking for the PID in the system and is not likely to find it as there is no client program running with that pid. It automatically deletes the file and is letting the user continue. Only time it really blocks, is if the user in fact is already running a client with that pid being active.

Comment: Pids get re-used. You already know that, I think, that's why you a fretting about the file getting deleted.  There's little point in using a scheme that *can* fail when there are schemes that *never* fail. It is even built into the .NET framework, IsSingleInstance property. But yes, it can be hard to give up on code you wrote ;) I can't help you cross that bridge

Comment: @HansPassant I do know that pids get reused.. and even though it's possible, the chances it will hapen is quite small (thougt not astronotically small). Now, I AM a beginner, please explain to me, just shortly, what a singleInstance program is. Because the way it sounds to me, it's not at all what this is. A single instance program to me sounds like a program that you can't start several times simultaneously. Which is the whole meaning with this program. A user should be able to run the sam program as many times as they wish, so long as they don't give exactly the same argument to it at start.

Comment: Based on that, if how I understand it in fact is correct, then your suggestion doesn't seem to be what I am looking for. If however I am wrong, I would be happy to give up the code for something that is much better. Just as you probably would change your gas for water to fuel your car, if you knew it worked and was better than what you are already using.

Comment: "Not the exact same arguments" is an entirely different angle that you never brought up before.  I'm giving up on this question, good luck with your program!

Comment: @HansPassant it was in the description, edit two: "Edit2: My comment was too long, so I guess it's best to just edit the question instead...

The file it's deleting is actually a file containing it's pid. The reason for having this file is to make sure that the user doesn't attempt to start the program twice with the same arguments (login information)."

Comment: @Rickard kill on Windows does not cleanly shut down a program, it just stops the main thread--potentially stopping it in the middle of an operation and corrupting data.  If your application were a GUI application, you could send it a WM_CLOSE message (which I guesst would be similar to signalling with SIGTERM in linux) but, you don't send it to a pid...

Comment: @PeterRitchie Thank you. :)  No, I understand I don't send it directly TO a pid.. you don't do that in linux either. In linux you (as to my knowledge) reference the pid so that the shell would know which process it's to deal with. :)

Answer (score 2):

A `Mutex` is something that represents mutual exclusion.  I don't think that is really what you want in this case. It's not really modelling what you want; plus only one application at time would be able to shut down.  I would recommend using a named `EventWaitHandle` to model one application sending events (shutdown events) to other applications.  If you use a manual reset event (by using `EventResetMode.ManualReset` when you create an `EventWaitHandle` object.

You would do this on a background thread that, when signalled, would marshal something over to the UI thread (via `Control.BeginInvoke`) to communicate to the main form that it needs to shut down.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a system wide event by using a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)

See the example on the linked page in the MSDN